# ¿Cómo puedo revisar el valor de un custom field en Wordpress desde el mismo panel?

Tags: php, wordpress

Tengo un custom field de (ACF) tipo checkbox. Necesito que al quedar marcada una casilla se mande un correo electrónico. Esta comprobación no se puede hacer desde los archivos del template ya que mandaría el mail cada vez que se visualiza la página. E.g.

```
[] Casilla 1
[X] Casilla mail --> Mandar un correo electrónico.
[] Casilla 3
```

Comment: Hola, ¿te valió la respuesta?

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente lo que quieres hacer es una `Options Page` de ACF, en esas páginas puedes poner diferentes `Custom Field` de manera que ahí pueden activar y desactivar ese `checkbox`.

La única limitación es que necesitas la licencia de `ACF Pro`

Aquí podrás encontrar más información:

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/options-page/

Si no es eso lo que buscar, por favor, amplia la pregunta.